# The difference java -cp java -jar

Tags: java, runtime

What is the difference in the running of the java program in Maven:

1:
java -jar target/join-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...

2:
java -cp target/MavenTestApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.koushik.javabrains.App

I think for the first one I need to have jar. Maybe it is connected with operating system. java -jar is on windows but java -cp is on linux or it does not matter? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The difference is in how JVM learns the start-up class (i.e. the one from which it takes the `public static main(String[])` method that needs to run first).

- With the `-cp` option you provide the name of the class on the command line
- With the `-jar` option, the name of the class is taken from the manifest file inside the JAR; the class path, if any, is also discarded.

Here is [the documentation that explains how the entry point is set with the manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

> If you have an application bundled in a JAR file, you need some way to indicate which class within the JAR file is your application's entry point. You provide this information with the Main-Class header in the manifest, which has the general form:
>
> ```
> Main-Class: classname
> ```
>
> The value classname is the name of the class that is your application's entry point.

Comment: In the `-jar` case the classpath is also dictated by the JAR manifest.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, you are executing the default main class mentioned in `manifest` file of the jar whereas in the second one, the `.jar` file is kept in classpath and the name of the main class to be executed is mentioned